# Why does my functional dependency conflict disappear when I expand the definition?

Tags: haskell, ghc, functional-dependencies, type-level-computation

I was trying to implement Integers at the type level in Haskell.  To start I implemented natural numbers with

```
data Zero
data Succ a
```

I then extended this to the integers with

```
data NegSucc a
```

I decided to then create an `Increment` class that would increment integers. Here is how I did that:

```
{-# Language FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# Language UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# Language MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# Language FlexibleInstances #-}

import Prelude ()

-- Peano Naturals --

data Zero
data Succ a

class Peano a
instance Peano Zero
instance (Peano a) => Peano (Succ a)

-- Integers --

data NegSucc a -- `NegSucc a` is -(a+1) so that 0 can only be expressed one way

class Integer a
instance (Peano a) => Integer a
instance (Peano a) => Integer (NegSucc a)

-- Arithmetic Operations --

class Increment a b | a -> b
instance (Peano a) => Increment a (Succ a)
instance Increment (NegSucc Zero) Zero
instance (Peano a) => Increment (NegSucc (Succ a)) (NegSucc a)
```

However when I run this GHC complains that `Functional dependencies conflict between instance declarations`, and cites all three of my increment instances.  This error doesn't make much sense to me, I don't see any conflict between the separate declarations.  What confuses me even further is that if I change the first instance to two separate instances

```
instance (Peano a) => Increment (Succ a) (Succ (Succ a))
instance Increment Zero (Succ Zero)
```

The compiler stops complaining altogether. However the rules that define `Peano a` tell me that these two things should be the same.

Why do I get a functional dependency conflict when I write the single line version but none when I write the two line version?

Comment: `NegSucc (NegSucc Zero)` is -(-(0 + 1) + 1) = -(-1 + 1) = -0 = 0, so you have multiple representations of 0 anyway.

Comment: Think about open world assumption. What if someone else make NegSucc an instance of Peano?

Comment: @melpomene `NegSucc (NegSucc Zero)` is not an `Integer`, because Integers are either peano numerals or the `NegSucc` of peano numerals.  `NegSucc (NegSucc Zero)` cannot be incremented either since only Integers can be incremented. You might be able to argue that `NegSucc (NegSucc Zero)` is equivalent to `Zero` but I don't think it is very meaningful.

Comment: @Yuras Your question leads me to understanding the difference.  If you would like to write up a full answer I'd be happy to accept. If you don't want to spend the time I'd be happy to write up the answer myself.

Comment: @WheatWizard sorry, I don't know enough about functional dependencies to make a real answer, I just made an intuitive guess. I hope someone will write an answer and describe all the technical details.

Answer (score 8):

*This answer is an expansion of [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50765194/why-does-my-functional-dependency-conflict-disappear-when-i-expand-the-definitio#comment88538387_50765194), which lead me to understanding what was going on*

In Haskell type classes are an open class, this means that new instances of the class can be made after the declaration.

This means that we cannot infer that `NegSucc a` is not a member of `Peano`, because it is always possible that it could be declared one later.

```
instance Peano (NegSucc a)
```

Thus when the compiler sees

```
instance (Peano a) => Increment a (Succ a)
instance Increment (NegSucc Zero) Zero
```

it cannot know that `NegSucc Zero` will not be an instance of `Peano`.  If `NegSucc Zero` is an instance of `Peano` it would increment to both `Zero` and `Succ (NegSucc Zero)`, which is a functional dependency conflict.  So we must throw an error.  The same applies to

```
instance (Peano a) => Increment (NegSucc (Succ a)) (NegSucc a)
```

Here `(NegSucc (Succ a))` could also be an instance of `Peano`.

The reason it looks as if there is no conflict is that we implicitly assume that there are not other instances of `Peano` than the ones that we know of.  When I transformed the single instance to two new isntances I made that assumption formal.

In the new code

```
instance (Peano a) => Increment (Succ a) (Succ (Succ a))
instance Increment Zero (Succ Zero)
```

it is not possible to add anything to preexisting type classes to cause a type to match multiple conflicting instances.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the error message I see with the original version:

```
negsucc.hs:28:10: error:
    Functional dependencies conflict between instance declarations:
      instance Peano a => Increment a (Succ a)
        -- Defined at negsucc.hs:28:10
      instance Increment (NegSucc Zero) Zero
        -- Defined at negsucc.hs:29:10
      instance Peano a => Increment (NegSucc (Succ a)) (NegSucc a)
        -- Defined at negsucc.hs:30:10
```

My loose understanding here is:

- the functional dependency `a -> b` means that GHC will "pattern match" on the type `a`, and will expect to discover `b` based on `a`.
- GHC **does not** include superclass constraints in this "pattern matching" logic. This is important. Intuitively, you know that NegSucc is not an instance of Peano. However GHC does not know how to look at a NegSucc and rule out the instance that requires `Peano NegSucc`. (This is simply a matter of knowing how GHC instance selection works. One could imagine that a future improvement to GHC might improve on this situation.)
- `instance Peano a => Increment a (Succ a)` will therefore always be selected by GHC, because it is the catch-all `Increment a`. Any other defined instances will conflict with this instance.

Now, isn't that what `UndecidableInstances` is for? To allow for conflicting instances, and allow GHC to select the most specific one that applies? You might think so. I thought so. However, note that the error message is specifically talking about the `Functional dependencies conflict`, meaning I don't think UndecidableInstances is implemented adequately to handle overlapping FunDeps in this way.

```
-- pseudocode for the fundep a -> b
increment a = Succ a
increment (NegSucc Zero) = Zero
increment (NegSucc (Succ a)) = NegSucc a
-- note that this is just pseudocode; unlike Haskell,
-- instead of trying cases from top to bottom
-- all cases will be tried simultaneously
```

However, this issue doesn't exist if you "expand" the definition, as you did.

```
-- pseudocode for the fundep a -> b with expanded defs
increment Zero = Succ Zero
increment (Succ a) = Succ (Succ a)
increment (NegSucc Zero) = Zero
increment (NegSucc (Succ a)) = NegSucc a
-- notice how there is now no overlap on the LHS pattern matches
```

You could also solve the problem by flipping the fundep around with the original defs.

```
-- pseudocode for the fundep b -> a with original defs
-- I called it "decrement" instead,
-- because from the b -> a point of view, that is what it does
decrement (Succ a) = a
decrement Zero = NegSucc Zero
decrement (NegSucc a) = NegSucc (Succ a)
-- notice how there is no overlap on the LHS pattern matches
```

I am stretching my own knowledge of fundeps here, so someone please correct me if I'm wrong.